# Passing Xml parameters to SQL stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I currently have a fairly large stored procedure which takes xml as a parameter and uses it to insert/update/delete several tables.

From a maintenance and organization of code standpoint  I think it would be cleaner if I made multiple stored procedures, 1 for each table.  My application would call a "main" stored procedure and that one would call the children stored procedures, passing the xml to them.  The actual logic of updating/inserting/deleting records would be contained in the children.

Are there negative performance implications to doing this?  If the xml is large, would additional memory be consumed by SQL Server as it passes the xml parameter, or does it pass by reference?

Comment: It is best to have one stored procedure do one and only one thing, makes it easier to debug and maintain code, I reckon you are on the right path.

Comment: That's good validation.  So in breaking up into multiple stored procedures, I need the main stored procedure to pass the xml parameter to subordinate stored procedures.  Does that copy the xml in memory, or just pass a pointer?